# Which word is right to be used?

Tags: word-choice

The time limit for contributors to hand in papers for inclusion in professor Park’s textbook is rapidly..... 
a) assigning 
B) setting 
C) approaching 
D) declaring

Answer (score 1):

The Correct word available would be "Approaching" as the limit is approaching.

Comment: Hello, Elliot. Questions are rarely considered acceptable (even if correct) on ELU if they don't contain supporting evidence (from a respected dictionary, say). If, as here , supporting evidence might be considered hardly necessary, then the question is not suitable for ELU and should be close-voted rather than answered.